# Error when running rackup with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am following [the Tuts+ Sinatra course](https://courses.tutsplus.com/courses/simple-sinatra/) and I am getting an error. Here is my code:

config.ru

```
require "./app"

run App
```

---

app.rb

```
require "sinatra/base"

IMAGES [
    { title: "Utopia",      url: "http://www.techno-utopia.com/techno-utopia.jpg" },
    { title: "Alaska",      url: "http://www.cruisebrothers.com/images/Destinations/Alaska.jpg" },
    { title: "The Unknown", url: "http://www.tasospagakis.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/fear_of_the_unknown_by_ilhaman-d4cukmg1.jpg" }
]

class App < Sinatra::Base
    get "/images" do
        @images = IMAGES
        erb :images
    end

    get "/images/:index" do |index|
        @image = IMAGES[index]
    end

    get "/" do
        "Hello world!"
    end

    post "/" do
        "Hello world via POST!"
    end

    put "/" do
        "Hello world via PUT!"
    end

    delete "/" do
        "Goodbye world via DELETE!"
    end

    get "/hello/:first_name/?:last_name?" do |first, last|
        "Hello #{first} #{last}"
    end
 end
```

---

/views/images.erb

```
<h1>Images</h1>

<% @images.each do |image| %>
    <h2><%= image[:title] %></h2>
    <img src="<%= image[:url] %>">
<% end %>
```

---

Here is the error when I run `rackup`:

[image: Error]

As always - thanks very much for any help you may be able to provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just miss a `=`

```
IMAGES = [
    { title: "Utopia",      url: "http://www.techno-utopia.com/techno-utopia.jpg" },
    { title: "Alaska",      url: "http://www.cruisebrothers.com/images/Destinations/Alaska.jpg" },
    { title: "The Unknown", url: "http://www.tasospagakis.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/fear_of_the_unknown_by_ilhaman-d4cukmg1.jpg" }
]
```

Variables are declared and assigned values by placing the variable name and the value either side of the assignment operator (=). [Source](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Understanding_Ruby_Variables#Declaring_a_Variable)

Comment: Clumsy error on my part - thanks very much good sir. Marked as correct and voted up.